# Setting up and running full IOTA Wallet

Tags: iri-node, wallet, error

Excuse me, can you please help me, when I launch IOTA Wallet (full version) with a few neighboring nodes added, the wallet reports following error:

```
12/28 16:55:24.416 [main] INFO  com.iota.iri.IRI - Welcome to IRI 1.4.1.4
Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\librocksdbjni7861117433009785088.dll: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
at org.rocksdb.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryFromJar(NativeLibraryLoader.java:78)
at org.rocksdb.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:56)
at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.loadLibrary(RocksDB.java:64)
at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.<clinit>(RocksDB.java:35)
at com.iota.iri.storage.rocksDB.RocksDBPersistenceProvider.<init>(RocksDBPersistenceProvider.java:28)
at com.iota.iri.Iota.initializeTangle(Iota.java:201)
at com.iota.iri.Iota.init(Iota.java:92)
at com.iota.iri.IRI.main(IRI.java:86)
12/28 16:55:41.945 [Shutdown Hook] INFO  com.iota.iri.IRI - Shutting down IOTA node, please hold tight...
12/28 16:55:47.956 [Shutdown Hook] ERROR com.iota.iri.IRI - Exception occurred shutting down IOTA node:
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.iota.iri.network.replicator.ReplicatorSourcePool.shutdown(ReplicatorSourcePool.java:76) ~[iri.jar:na]
at com.iota.iri.network.replicator.Replicator.shutdown(Replicator.java:30) ~[iri.jar:na]
at com.iota.iri.Iota.shutdown(Iota.java:176) ~[iri.jar:na]
at com.iota.iri.IRI.lambda$shutdownHook$0(IRI.java:259) ~[iri.jar:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
Process exited with status 1
```

---

[image]

---

#### Why do I get such an error and what can I do about it?

Comment: Is your installed Java version 64 bit? Full node does not run on 32-bit Java on Windows as they don't provide native libraries for 32-bit Windows. Install 64-bit Java instead.

Comment: Is there a solution about the problem? I have the same thing error. Fullnode, Windows 64 bit, newest wallet 1.4.1.6 iri. Same Error. When i run Light Wallet with Public node it works, but if i want to run wallet with full node and with costum http://localhost:14265 then i have error in wallet "No Connection" No Connection to remote node. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Seems rocksDB related setup. Did you use instructions from a walkthrough guide such as http://iota.partners/ ?
Also running a full node which will not be online 24/7 is a bad idea it wont help the network a great deal. In other words refrain from running the full node wallet on desktops and laptops.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have installed 64 bit Java is ok. I get the same error when I build the iri with maven (mvn clean compile passess ok, in mvn package there is the problem): Tests in error:
  com.iota.iri.BundleValidatorTest: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\librocksdbjni16850478755329069913.dll: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. There is no RocksDB dll  in this directory:

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp

Yes, this is surely the problem is with the RocksDB dll, which is quite important component of the IRI. Does anybody know how to fix this ?